# SQL function with multiple default parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know, if there is any possible way in SQL to distinguish which one of default parameters was set when function was called?
F.e. if there is function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someFunction (
ID NUMBER,
showNames VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N',
showAddress VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N')
```

and it will be called like that:

```
someFunction(123, 'Y')
```

is there any way to distinguish which parameter was set by 'Y'? Or if I need to set showAddress to 'Y' do I have to call function like that:

```
someFunction(123, 'N', 'Y')
```

Comment: I'm tagging this question "oracle" because the use of `varchar2` suggests Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use Oracle database you could specify exact param name:

```
   someFunction(123, showAddress =>'Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged as `Oracle`; you can use named parameter like `formal => actual`. So in your case, you can say `someFunction(123, shownames => 'Y')` in which case ID and shownames will be set; whereas showaddress will have default value.

Otherwise, it's all positional parameter and hence calling `someFunction(123, 'Y')` will set ID and then shownames based on position of the parameters.

See more here

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825

Answer (score 0):

After trying this method:

```
 someFunction(123, showAddress =>'Y')
```

I've got exception message: 
`ORA-00907: missing right parentesis.`
This problem exist only when I am using `showAddress =>'Y'` - when I use just `someFunction(123)` everything works fine.
Can it be caused by using old ORACLE version? (I am using 10.2 at the moment).